# Using getText() for the getting property in Struts 2

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, resourcebundle

I am working on the Struts2 framework with JSP.

In my `samplePrj.properties` file, in that

```
com.samplePrj.Successmessage = Saved Successful
```

is an attribute. I need to use this value in my JSP page, using Struts2.

so how can I get the value of `"com.samplePrj.Successmessage"` in my JSP page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`text`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/text.html) tag

```
<s:i18n name="samplePrj">
    <s:text name="com.samplePrj.Successmessage" />
</s:i18n>
```

it will load the bundle using [`i18n`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/i18n.html) tag from `samplePrj.properties` and print the value from key `com.samplePrj.Successmessage` in it.

or you can use it with `getText()` but your action class should extend `ActionSupport`.

```
<s:property value="getText('com.samplePrj.Successmessage')"/>
```

Comment: Sir, I want to check a variable value with the .property file value. How can we do it?? i.e using if condition (a == the property file value)

Comment: If the variable is in the value stack then you can use it in the OGNL expression in the `if` tag's `test` attribute. Like `<s:if test="myVariable == getText('com.samplePrj.Successmessage')">`

Answer (score 1):

You can use getText() method to read from properties files.

```
<s:set var="variable" value="getText('com.samplePrj.Successmessage')"/>
<s:if test="myVariable == #variable"> 
  //do what u want
</s:if>
```